# Excel - macro to select cell in workbook with current date

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I'm creating a calendar/schedule workbook in Excel. It has a worksheet for each month.

Now I need to create a `CommandButton` which takes me to the cell which contains the current date. There's only one cell with the current date, but it can be on any sheet of the workbook.

I've been searching for days now, but can't get it right!

Things I've been trying:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim Loc As Range

For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With Sh.UsedRange
        Set Loc = .Cells.Find(What:=Int(Date), LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
            Do Until Loc Is Nothing
                Loc.Select
                Set Loc = .FindNext(Loc)
            Loop
        End If
    End With
    Set Loc = Nothing

Next

End Sub
```

This kinda works when the cell with the current date is on the same sheet (although it keeps reselecting the cell until I press Esc), but fails when the cell is on another sheet.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Here's an example of how to apply code on the Workbook level rather than the worksheet level, so that you don't have to use a loop http://ccm.net/faq/20153-excel-apply-vba-code-to-multiple-sheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a Do While loop. Since you're only looking for the one, this simple For/Next should do. Once it's found the code exits the loop and goes to the Select section at end. If the date isn't found nothing is selected:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim Loc As Range

For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With Sh.UsedRange
        Set Loc = .Cells.Find(What:=Int(Date), LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
            Exit For
        End If
    End With
Next
If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
    'need to activate parent sheet before selecting cell
    Loc.Parent.Activate
    Loc.Select
End If
End Sub
```

Note that before you can select a range you need to activate the parent sheet.

Comment: He already had a loop. The only shortcoming of my answer was that it didn't improve on his answer by getting him out of having to use these loops, as the method I found to search all sheets was the same as yours. I based it on http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=36968  Try to find a vectorized answer.

Comment: @Hack-R Please note that the For loop is only through the sheets. That's how it's done. Then in each sheet, it's either found or not. I'm not sure what you mean by "the method I found". Are you saying you downvoted mine because it was like yours? If so, that's an incorrect use of a downvote, which is supposed to reflect whether an answer addresses the question and works.

Comment: I disagree with the downvote if it was for the fact that there is a for loop in there. What's more is that the for loop that is being used is only to loop through worksheets, which is such a small portion of what's being executed. +1 for the answer. Simple and effective.